# How to correctly import image to interface in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi4

I am making a photo booth in python. I am using tkinter to do that:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
import os
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
load = Image.open("./image1.jpg")

def startCallBack():
    tf = Tk()
    render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
    img = Label(tf, image=render)
    img.image = render
    img.pack()
    root.destroy()
    tf.mainloop()

root = Tk()

appHighlightFont = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=48, weight='bold')
label=Label(root, text='PHOTO BOOTH', font=appHighlightFont)
btn = Button( root, text ="START", command = startCallBack )
label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.4,anchor="center")
btn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6,anchor="center")
root.mainloop()
```

But when I start this script an error appears:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "photobooth.py", line 10, in startCallBack
img = Label(tf, image=render)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2766, in __init__
Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
(widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

Image is in the same directory as the script and I am using Raspberry Pi 4B 4GB RAM

Please Help!

Comment: Try running the script from the same directory.

Comment: @IbrahimYousuf I am running script from the same directory!

Comment: Please edit your question,and show us a minimal example of your code.

Comment: Maybe you use many `Tk()` instances at the same time.

Comment: Well... I forgot to add
`tf.mainloop()`
At the end of script but it still doesn't work

Comment: maybe showing full code will help

Comment: Multiple calls to `Tk()` will definitely cause problems like this.  You need to use `Toplevel()` instead to create additional windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i ran your script and it works perfectly. I don't know if you have multiple tkinter windows in your project but if this the case, use `render= ImageTk.PhotoImage(master=tf,image = load)` instead of `render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)`. This will solve the issue.
If you don't have multiple windows, try to create your render variable before creating your PhotoImage like this

```
render = 0
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
```

I don't know why this work but i solved similar issues with this sevral times.
I hope one of my solutions will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I forgot to add

```
tf.mainloop()
```

At the end of script

Thanks for your help!